# invalid types 'int [3][double]' for array subscript

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

When compiling a "arduino tamagotchi" I get the message

> invalid types 'int [3][double]' for array subscript

What might be the issue?

Set before the `void loop()`

```
float poopometer=0;
int poops [3] = {
  0,0,0,
};
```

The reported error is on the line:

```
poops[round(poopometer)]=random(20,display.width()+32);
```

```
void loop() {
  
  button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
  button2State = digitalRead(button2Pin);
  button3State = digitalRead(button3Pin);

  //char* str = "";
  
  if(!dead){
    /* -------- MODIFY PET STATS -------- */
    // TODO: different gradients regarding to age
    if(sleeping){
      hunger-=0.00005;
      poopometer+=0.00005;
      if(happiness-0.0001>0){
        happiness-=0.0001;
      }
      health-=0.00005+countPoops()*0.0001;
      if(discipline-0.0001>0){
        discipline-=0.0001;
      }
    }else{
      hunger-=0.00025;
      poopometer+=0.00025;
      if(happiness-0.0002>0){
        happiness-=0.0002;
      }
      health-=0.0001+countPoops()*0.0001;
      if(discipline-0.0002>0){
        discipline-=0.0002;
      }
      //discipline-=0.02;
    }
    age+=0.0000025;

    //diarrhea :) for testing
    //poopometer+=0.005;

    //health-=1;
    //health-=countPoops()*0.0001;
    //health-=countPoops()*0.05;

    if(poopometer>=10){
      poopometer=countPoops();
      poops[round(poopometer)]=random(20,display.width()+32);
           
      if(soundEnabled){
        tone(sound,200,50);
      }
      poopometer=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `round` function returns a floating point number (`double`), you need to convert it into an integer. Always check the documentation, see: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/
like this:

```c
poops[(int)round(poopometer)]=random(20,display.width()+32);
```

Only positive integer values can be used as a index.